# How to compensate biased estimations

Tags: expectation-maximization, unbiased-estimator

I have a biased MLE procedure which is embedded in an EM algorithm. Since the MLE is biased the EM algorithm does not converge, so when it reach the real value $x_0$ it estimates $x_0 - \epsilon$ and the EM estimations keeps decreasing rather than staying at the real value.

Do you know any way to compensate this biasedness so the EM would be stable?

Comment: What about bias-correction procedures?